# How to add tabs to a tab bar controller? (iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I've started an Xcode project with the default tab based layout and i can't seem to figure it out. I open the main .xib and add a third tab, then associate the tab to the third .xib file, yet when i touch the third tab, the application crashes.

Error code:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "thirdview" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This error generally means that while your tab bar controller is finding the .xib file that you associated it with, that .xib does not have a link for the `view` outlet from its "File's Owner" item. Double-check that you've set this property correctly. (Most xibs will just set it to the view they contain.)

Comment: How do i check that i've set that correctly, and how do i make that connection? Thanks.

Comment: Open the .xib file and select the "File's Owner" item. In the inspector (separate window in Xcode 3, right pane in Xcode 4), open the Links tab. One of those links should be called `view` with a small circle next to it. Make sure that circle is filled and when you hover over it, your View highlights - if not, drag-and-drop from the circle onto your view object.